Increate RAM usage when parsing json dataframe column
tl;dr - My RAM consumption is huge and I don't know why.
I have This function To calculated the RAM usage on my server:


def log_memory_usage():
    memory_info = psutil.virtual_memory()
    memory_used_gb = memory_info.used / (1024**3)  # Convert to GB
    logger.info(f"System-wide memory used: {memory_used_gb:.2f} GB")



I have a dataframe column that is a stringified json.
When looking at the RAM consumption using the function above and df.info(memory_usage='deep' I get weird results:


2024-10-30 14:34:44,016 [semantic population]: INFO : System-wide memory used: 2.41 GB
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 363925 entries, 0 to 367312
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count   Dtype
---  ------                 --------------   -----
 0   table_id               363925 non-null  object
 1   table                  363925 non-null  object
 2   table_from_name_field  363925 non-null  object
 3   column                 363925 non-null  object
 4   source_data            363925 non-null  object
 5   schema                 363925 non-null  object
 6   openai_res             363925 non-null  object
dtypes: object(7)
memory usage: 3.3 GB



I have no idea how the whole RAM is 2.41GB and the dataframe is 3.3.
Next I run a function to change the JSON column to his keys:


def get_row(row):
            try:
                js = json.loads(row['openai_res'])
                row['description'] = js['description']
                row['business_term'] = js['business_term']
                row['explanation'] = js['explanation']
                row['columns'] = js['columns']
                row['openai_res'] =  pd.NA
                del js
                return row
            except ValueError as e:
                return    
df = df.progress_apply(get_row,axis=1)



The results are even more weird:


<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 363925 entries, 0 to 367312
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count   Dtype
---  ------                 --------------   -----
 0   table_id               355757 non-null  object
 1   table                  355757 non-null  object
 2   table_from_name_field  355757 non-null  object
 3   column                 355757 non-null  object
 4   source_data            355757 non-null  object
 5   schema                 355757 non-null  object
 6   openai_res             0 non-null       object
 7   description            355757 non-null  object
 8   business_term          355757 non-null  object
 9   explanation            355757 non-null  object
 10  columns                355757 non-null  object
dtypes: object(11)
memory usage: 980.0 MB
2024-10-30 14:42:59,203 [business_terms.py]: INFO : None
2024-10-30 14:42:59,207 [semantic population]: INFO : System-wide memory used: 24.07 GB



So my questions are:

What is the right way to measure how much RAM my dataframe is taking?
If I do that the right way, How Do I free all of the RAM that is taken by the json parsing?
I think it's OS related. This happens on my AmazonLinux EC2 Server, but on my MacBook Pro the RAM consumption is pretty similar.

Thank you, I really don't understand this behavior in my server is crashing due to OOM

Note that you really want to ask one question at a time. This might help with your first. How do I determine the size of an object in Python?
